# Rust learning question tree example. Update element inside Rc

Tags: rust, weak-references

I'm studying rust and I'm stuck on a question about Rc, Weak and RefCell. The use case is to implement a fully functioning tree, where each node has one parent and a list of children. The documentation provides a good starting point:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    parent: RefCell<Weak<Node>>,
    children: RefCell<Vec<Rc<Node>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let leaf = Rc::new(Node {
        value: 3,
        parent: RefCell::new(Weak::new()),
        children: RefCell::new(vec![]),
    });

    println!("leaf parent = {:?}", leaf.parent.borrow().upgrade());

    let branch = Rc::new(Node {
        value: 5,
        parent: RefCell::new(Weak::new()),
        children: RefCell::new(vec![Rc::clone(&leaf)]),
    });

    *leaf.parent.borrow_mut() = Rc::downgrade(&branch);

    println!("leaf parent = {:?}", leaf.parent.borrow().upgrade());
}
```

But. When I try to expand upon this, there's a problem with the design. I cannot add a new node to an already consisting one. The `branch` node has a child, but this I think is only possible because we already know `leaf` is going to be the one and only child before `branch` is created. If this is not the case, can we somehow change `branch` after it already has been created inside an `Rc` and add `leaf` as a child?

Or should I leave this design and adopt a design that looks more like:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    parent: Weak<RefCell<Node>>,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new leaves with the following code:

```rust
let new_leaf = Rc::new(Node {
    value: 4,
    parent: RefCell::new(Rc::downgrade(&branch)),
    children: RefCell::new(vec![])
});

branch.children.borrow_mut().push(new_leaf);
```

That being said your alternative suggested `Node` type seems to be what most rustaceans would go with / are more familiar with.

Comment: Clearly I don't understand Rc well enough. So apparently you can mutate an object within Rc as long as one of its members is wrapped with RefCell? I knew it could be done with a direct Rc<RefCell<SomeType>>, but not with Rc<SomeType{ RefCell < SomeMemberType > } >. Thanks.

Comment: That's the point of `RefCell` it allowes mutation of it's content and only requires a shared reference for that as you can see in the signature `fn borrow_mut(&self) -> RefMut<'_, T>` where `RefMut<'_, T>` is essentially a mutable reference `&mut T` plus runtime reference counting.